# gcc transformation pass for ackermann

Tags: optimization, gcc

`gcc` (I tried `4.7.2` on Mac and Linux with `-O3` flag) optimizes ackermann function to a single call with a big local stack. An example Ackermann code below:

```
int ack(int m,int n){
  if(m == 0) return n+1;
  if(n == 0) return ack(m-1,1);
  return ack(m-1,ack(m,n-1));
}
```

When disassembled, there is only one recursive call to `ack` function, instead of two calls (I couldn't parse what is going on -`ack` is now transformed by gcc into a function with 8 arguments, and local stack of 49 int and 9 char). I tried to look up what kind of transformation passes gcc did to optimize Ackermann function to a single call, but didn't find anything of interest. I will appreciate pointers on what major transformation passes gcc performed to convert the deeply recursive Ackermann to a single recursive call. LLVM gcc (I tried v4.2 on mac) doesn't reduce it to single recursive call yet, and is 4x slower with `-O3` flag. This optimization seems very interesting.

Comment: You should also see where the speed falls on that system and version of gcc with -O1 and -O2. The man page lists a lot of (if not all) the optimizations done at each step, so if it's something specifically between one of those, you maybe can narrow it down.

Comment: It isn't that hard to replace a call to the function itself by a goto to the beginning of the function (didn't check if that's what is happening) in case of a terminal recursion.

Comment: @MarcGlisse, Ackermann is a special case of deep recursive functions. I am aware of tail recursion technique for other recursive functions like Fibonacci. Converting Fibonacci to tail-recursive function is pretty simple, but not Ackermann as far as I know.

Comment: That's why there is still one call left instead of 0... After the last call to ack, you don't need to go back to the calling function, so you can replace the call by a jump.

Comment: It seems to be sibling call optimization. Turning on just foptimize-sibling-calls flag in say -O1, reproduces this optimization, and turning it off, turns it off. If any one has more pointers on how this transformation is done in context of Ackermann function, please feel free to answer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The first pass is tail-call elimination. GCC does this at most optimization levels. Essentially, all function calls in tail position are transformed into goto's, like this:

```
int ack(int m, int n) {
begin:
  if (m == 0) return n + 1;
  if (n == 0) { m -= 1; n = 1; goto begin; }
  n = ack(m, n-1); m -= 1; goto begin;
}
```

Now there is only one recursive call remaining and GCC, at -O3 level only, inlines this for a couple of iterations. Resulting in the huge monster you saw.